Crypto++ library x5519 shared key generation error
I am using Crypto++ library to sign and verify with ed25519 signature scheme by underlying Donna functions. I generated two key pair and then I try to generate shared key for both side by function curve25519_mult .But the key generated twice is not the same.
What is the problem with the code below?
#include <donna.h>
#include <osrng.h>
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
static CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

//Generate random private keys
unsigned char private_key1[32],private_key2[32];
prng.GenerateBlock(private_key1, 32);
prng.GenerateBlock(private_key2, 32);

//Generate public keys
unsigned char public_key1[32],public_key2[32];
CryptoPP::Donna::ed25519_publickey(public_key1, private_key1);
CryptoPP::Donna::ed25519_publickey(public_key2, private_key2);

//Generate shared key
unsigned char shared_secret1[32],shared_secret2[32];
CryptoPP::Donna::curve25519_mult(shared_secret1, private_key1, publicKey2);
CryptoPP::Donna::curve25519_mult(shared_secret2, private_key2, publicKey1);

//Assertion failed!
assert(::memcmp(shared_secret1,shared_secret2,32) == 0);
}

What I done:

I searched through the Internet for answer,not solved.
I checked my own code,no bug found.
I tested signing and verification.They are OK.

I just need to generate a shared key for the two key pair holders.

X25519 and Ed25519 keys are not readily interchangeable, i.e. Ed25519 keys cannot simply be used for X25519. However, Ed25519 keys can be converted to X25519 keys, see here. This step seems to be missing in your implementation (I cannot say whether Crypto++ supports that conversion).
